# How do I get my model into my view using C#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have deserialized my JSON response into an object. What are the next steps? I have a WebAPI controller that I currently working with my JSON object. I need to take this data and move it into a view so that I can connect it to my web components.

I guess I'm confused on if I should iterate through my JSON object in the controller or in the view? I have the following:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData.RootObject>(Data);
foreach (var record in Data.rows)
{
    foreach (var nestedRecord in record.f)
    {
         List<string> list = new List<string>();
         list.Add(nestedRecord.v);         
    }
}
return View();
```

Also, I'm iterating through this model and I cannot return the model in the view since it's outside the scope.

Comment: Your list of `nestedRecord.v` strings is what you want as a model for your view?

Comment: For starters, add the model to your view. return View(viewmodel);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two popular options here, depending on how much information you might potentially access from the deserialized object. One, use the `MyData.RootObject` as your model, and iterate it in the view. This would give you the greatest flexibility if you need to access other properties of the object:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData.RootObject>(Data);
return View(model);
```

In the view (this unordered-list markup is only a sample), you might have:

```
@model MyData.RootObject

<ul>
@foreach (var record in Model.rows)
{
    foreach (var nestedRecord in record.f)
    {
        <li>@nestedRecord.v</li>
    }
}
</ul>
```

Or, continue as you had planned, but move the list you're populating outside of the for-loops, using the list as the model. This would be the least flexible in terms of rendering your object in the view:

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData.RootObject>(Data);
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (var record in rootObject.rows)
{
    foreach (var nestedRecord in record.f)
    {
        list.Add(nestedRecord.v);         
    }
}
return View(list);
```

And your view in this case (much more concise than the other option):

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<string>

<ul>
@foreach (var record in Model)
{
    <li>@record</li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: You beautiful SOB. This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!